# Aggregate data by a relative 30-day inverval

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I got a dataframe with these columns: product, product_launch_date, date, revenue. How can I calculate the aggregated revenue by a 30-day interval by products?

The product_launch_date is repeated in rows for each distinct product.

```
df['days_since_launch'] = (df['date'] -  df['product_launch_date']).dt.days
```

I want to bucket the 'days_since_launch' for each product in a 30-day interval. A stupid way is to map out mannually:

```
con1 = df['days_since_launch']<= 30
con2 = df['days_since_launch']> 30 |df['days_since_launch'] <= 60
...
df['date_bucket'] = 0
df.loc[con1, 'date_bucket'] = 1
df.loc[con2, 'date_bucket'] = 2
...
```

And finally, I can use groupby to aggregate by the date_bucket:

```
df.groupby(['product', 'date_bucket'])['revenue'].agg('sum').reset_index()
```

The question is how to generate the date_bucket in a smart way?
Thanks.

Comment: @QuangHoang: oops I was linking to question. seems like it got link to my deleted answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65698498/drop-overlapping-periods-less-than-6-months-in-pandas-datafram

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use `pd.cut`:

```
df['days_since_launch'] = (df['date'] -  df['product_launch_date']).dt.days

bins = np.arange(df['days_since_launch'].min(), df['days_since_launch'].max()+1, 30)

df['date_bucket'] = pd.cut(df['days_since_launch'], bins=bins, labels=False)
```